# How to get the required digit of number from an scope object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the object i need to pick-up only the digit what i required. example i have a `Number` with 3 digit, i want to show first digit in first `span` second in second span like so.

how to get? is there a filter approach to do this?
Here is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
        $scope.digital = 849;
        $scope.total = 105631466;
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <span class"firstDigit">{{digital}}</span><!-- only first digit(8) -->
        <span class"secondDigit">{{digital}}</span> <!-- only second digit(4) -->
        <span class"thridDigit">{{digital}}</span> <!-- only third digit(9) -->
        <span>{{total}}</span> <!-- need to show like 75,688,6497 (adding commas) -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/1/)

Comment: `<span>{{digital | number}}</span>` will format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `$scope.digital` to an array using `$scope.digitalArray = $scope.digital.toString().split('');`

And then use `ng-repeat` to loop through the new array.

This make it so you can have any length of integer and they will all appear

Using `{{total | number}}` will format it with commas like you are lookoing for

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/4/)

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.digital = 849;
    //Could also use $scope.digitalArray = $scope.digital.toString();
    //But I think it's better for learning purposes to split it into an array
    $scope.digitalArray = $scope.digital.toString().split('');
    $scope.total = 105631466;

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <div ng-repeat="n in digitalArray">
            <span>{{n}}</span><!-- only first digit(8) -->
        </div>
        <span>{{total | number}}</span> <!-- need to show like 75,688,6497 (adding commas) -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To format total as a number you can do:

`<span>{{ total | number }}</span>`

For more documentation on formatting numbers with angular see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number.

To split the integer, it makes the most sense to convert it to a string in your controller and access the indexes one at a time.

In the controller:

`$scope.digits = $scope.digital.toString();`

And then you update your html to access each of the indexes individually:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <span class"firstDigit">{{digits[0]}}</span><!-- only first digit(8) -->
        <span class"secondDigit">{{digits[1]}}</span> <!-- only first digit(4) -->
        <span class"thridDigit">{{digits[2]}}</span> <!-- only first digit(9) -->
        <span>{{ total | number }}</span> <!-- need to show like 75,688,6497 (adding commas) -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can do the following:

```
var digits = (""+$scope.digital).split("");
```

This will give you an array that you can then iterate through for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mathematic solution but...  you can use a function like:

```
$scope.extactNumber = function(number, pos){
   return (number + "").substring(pos, pos + 1)
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.split = function(num) {
    return (''+num).split('');
};
```

This will take a number as `num`, convert it to a string, and then turn that string into an array, with each item being a digit. Then, to access a digit, you just use the normal array accessor, as shown below.

In your HTML:

```
<span>{{split(digital)[0]}}</span> <!-- your first digit -->
<span>{{split(digital)[1]}}</span> <!-- your second digit, etc. -->
```

Better yet, to cut down on the number of times you call split, you can just put each individual number into an array to begin with, and just access them later:

```
myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.digital = split(849);
    $scope.total = split(105631466);
});

function split(num) {
    return (''+num).split('');
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<span>{{digital[0]}}</span> <!-- your first digit -->
<span>{{digital[1]}}</span> <!-- your second digit, etc. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directive for this task and do it simply like this.

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.digital = 849;
    $scope.total = 105631466;
});

myApp.directive('myDigitsDirective', function () {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.chars = scope.digits.toString().split('');
    }

    return {
        template: '<span ng-repeat="char in chars track by $index" ng-class="digit-{{$index}}">{{char}}</span><span>{{total}}</span>',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            digits: '=myDigitsDirective',
            total: '=total'
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <div my-digits-directive="digital" total="total"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/6/)